# extend python not extending correctly

Tags: python

I have a list `indexlist` with the value:

`[8, 11, 4, 3]`

This is in the middle of a function, so other relevant values are `i=0` and `endsorted = sorted(indexlist[i+1:])`

Then I call

`indexlist[:i+1].extend(endsorted)`

which returns

`[8, 11, 4, 3]`.

Shouldn't it return `[8, 3, 4, 11]`? I've checked `indexlist[:i+1]`, which is `[8]`, and I've checked `endsorted` which is `[3, 4, 11]`.

Comment: No, it shouldn't, because you're extending a copy of part of the list (a slice) that you're not saving anywhere. This is not what extend or slicing is for.

Comment: What you _can_ do is set a slice directly, like `some_list[2:3] = [2, 4, 6, 8]`, although it's still a little weird/hard to read in most contexts I can imagine.

Comment: you're right, thanks

Comment: your title is misleading - it's you who did it wrong, not the computer

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC like always?

Answer (score 0):

Look on that code:

```
# Init
indexlist = [8, 11, 4, 3]

# Your setup
i = 0
endsorted = sorted(indexlist[i+1:])

# Extending the right list object
new_index_list = indexlist[:i+1]
new_index_list.extend(endsorted)
```

The new_index_list value is `[8, 3, 4, 11]`.

Since I extended the right object and not just a copy of it(When slicing a list you get a new object and not the original one)